# Method works with literal value but not with variable holding the same value

Tags: java, android

Code below.

The ObjectAnimator object "**slideUpTranslate**" works just fine.  It slides the ImageView upward.

**slideDownTranslate**, however, doesn't work at all unless a literal value is supplied in lieu of the integer variable "menuHeight".  It doesn't throw an error of any kind, it just does nothing when you press the slide down button.

I've tried manually initializing menuHeight to an arbitrary value in the onCreate call.  I've tried designating it as a float instead of an integer.  I've tried using different variables for each of the ObjectAnimator objects.  I've tried instantiating slideDownTranslate with exactly the same parameters as slideUpTranslate.  No cigar.  I really don't see a reason why slideDownTranslate isn't working.

```
    Button slideUpButton;
    Button slideDownButton;
    ImageView menuView;
    int menuHeight;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        slideUpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slideUpButton);
        slideDownButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slideDownButton);
        menuView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menuView);

        menuView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menucropped);

        //This works
        final ObjectAnimator slideUpTranslate = 
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menuView,View.TRANSLATION_Y, menuHeight * -1);
        slideUpTranslate.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

        //This does nothing
        final ObjectAnimator slideDownTranslate = 
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menuView,View.TRANSLATION_Y, menuHeight);
        slideDownTranslate.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());


        menuView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               menuHeight = menuView.getHeight();
                menuView.setTranslationY(menuHeight);
            }
        });

        slideUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideUpTranslate.start();
                Log.i("Test", "Slide up clicked...  Height:" + Integer.toString(menuHeight));
            }
        });

        slideDownButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideDownTranslate.start();
                Log.i("Test", "Slide down clicked...  Height:" + Integer.toString(menuHeight));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

So in short, this works:

```
final ObjectAnimator slideDownTranslate = 
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menuView,View.TRANSLATION_Y, 500);
```

But this doesn't:

```
final ObjectAnimator slideDownTranslate = 
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menuView,View.TRANSLATION_Y, menuHeight);
```

To further complicate things, **slideUpTranslate** works with either a literal value *or* a variable.  They're exactly the same, yet one works with a variable in the third parameter slot and one does not.

Going to wind up in the nut house if I can't figure this out soon!  Save me!

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not working". Is it behaving unexpectedly? Does it throw a compiler error? A runtime error? What does the error say?

Comment: It doesn't do anything.  No errors at all.  Logs set up in the button listeners are displaying the right values for menuHeight.  slideUpTranslate slides the image up, but slideDownTranslate doesn't do anything unless I set the third parameter to a literal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the value of menuView *after* it's first used to create the animations. Unless there is some hidden assignment of menuItem I can't see, you're passing a value of (menuHeight == 0) to both animators.  Then, when you log the value of menuHeight later in your onclick handlers, you're seeing the reassigned value of menuHeight from the Runnable that executed later.

You might want to consider assigning your animators at the very last moment before they are started instead of initializing them in onCreate().

Comment: You're right.  I was paying too much attention to what the logs in the button listeners were saying.  By then menuHeight had been assigned the correct value, but the animators were receiving zeroes in onCreate.  It just so happened that "0" animated to the right spot for the upward translate.  Which means I need to rethink a couple other things.  Thanks a bunch!